# How to show a table based on drop-down value?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a drop-down menu on an HTML which has values from the database table. It fetches the value from the table and shows in the drop-down menu. In that table, I have other columns also. I want to show a table on the HTML page below the drop-down menu on the selection of drop-down value which shows the other column values from the table based on that drop-down value i.e It fetches the values from that row of the selected value. How can I do that? My drop-down menu code is here:

```html
<label>Courses</label>
<select name="courses" id="courses" class="dropdownclass">
<option selected="selected" value="" disabled selected hidden>-- Select an option --</option>
<?php  
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('db');

$sql = "SELECT courses FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 
    echo "<option value=' " . $row['courses'] ."'>" . $row['courses'] ."</option>";
}

?>
</select>
```

Comment: on select fetch value using ajax call and show a table.

Comment: Can you please give me the code

Comment: you have way too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax.

```
$("#courses").change(function(){
var course = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
 url:'your php page url',
type:'post',
data:'course='+course,
success:function(response){
// your drop down box is in response
}
});
});
```

Comment: what i have to give in select tag?

Comment: In the select tag use id and the append all ajax response to it.

Comment: Share your table structure.

Comment: I want to populate a table based on the value selected from drop down value. So where do I add the table?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a dependable drop-down menu I think. To make it smoothly, you can take help of **Ajax**
Ajax gives the real-time experience of making this. 
TO make this at first give id for each option in drop-down menu. After that, according to this value get second value. See the below code for reference.

```
$("#courses").change(function(){
   var course = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
   url:'your php page url',
   type:'post',
   data:'course='+course,
   success:function(response){
   // your drop down box is in response
   },
   error:function(response){
   // your error message
   },

  });
});
```

after that make a page by **php** for giving response that will be shown in html page. You can check the below link for complete code

[Clik here to see the drop-down menu complete code](https://github.com/arif98741/dependable_dropdown_menu)

Comment: You can easily modify the code according to your needs.

Comment: Is there any way other than ajax

Comment: Yes you can do it by php. This process will refresh your page

Comment: You don't need jQuery for that, I would highly recommend using the standard modern version of making requests with `fetch` instead

Comment: where do i add the table?